# JS works in IE, Safari, Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Most my work is done running on Webkit stuff and using Chrome's dev tools. But this code doesn't run in Firefox; it doesn't even throw a console error so I have no idea what's wrong. Any ideas. I'm sure its terribly easy. My code is designed to look throw a div for a specific syntax "t_" "r_" which are references to an external document; I'm trying to find all said references and replace them with hyperlink. I"m a novice JS coder so sorry for the naiveness you'll undoubtedly see in here.

(I'm using FF 22.0)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function pre_forwarder(){ //First Step
patt_1=/\[r_/g;
patt_2=/\[t_/g;
patt_S_and_R_1 = "[r_";
patt_S_and_R_2 = "[t_";
forwarder(patt_1,patt_S_and_R_1);
forwarder(patt_2,patt_S_and_R_2);
}
function forwarder(Pattern,Pre_SearchReplace){
rule_string = document.getElementById("divid");
rule_string = rule_string.innerText;
var patt1 = Pattern;
while (patt1.test(rule_string)==true) 
      {
      begin_string = patt1.lastIndex;
      fullpar_string = patt1.lastIndex + 5;
      partial_string = rule_string.slice(begin_string,fullpar_string); //5 characters
      //alert("partial_string-"+partial_string);
      refined_string_end = partial_string.indexOf("]");
      refined_str = partial_string.slice(0,refined_string_end); //raw number
      full_str = Pre_SearchReplace+refined_str+"]"; //restructured
      SectionNum = refined_str;
      SearchReplace = full_str; //Variable to pass to parse()
      //alert("S&R="+SearchReplace+" >> full_string-"+full_str);
      //alert("S&R"+SearchReplace+">>SecNum-"+SectionNum+">>Pre-Search-"+Pre_SearchReplace);
      Parse(SearchReplace,SectionNum,Pre_SearchReplace);
      }
 //var patt_end=/\[t_/g;
 }
function Parse(SearchReplace,SectionNum,Pre_SearchReplace){
if (Pre_SearchReplace == patt_S_and_R_1){
ref_URL = "UEB_Ref.html#";
}else if (Pre_SearchReplace == patt_S_and_R_2){
ref_URL = "UEB_Tech.html#";
}
linkCreate = '<a href="javascript:Dude(\''+ref_URL+SectionNum+'\');">Link to ch-'+SectionNum+'</a> ';
document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML.replace(SearchReplace, linkCreate);
}
function Dude(SectionNum){
alert(SectionNum);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="pre_forwarder();">
<button onclick="pre_forwarder();">
New Tool</button>
<div id="divid">
hello [dude] ok the end [r_12.1][r_7] [r_22]
<br>bro try this [t_15.3][t_6] [t_5.5]
</div>
<div id="hyperlink">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This needs 1) formatting and 2) a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You've `rule_string = rule_string.innerText;` at line 15. FF doesn't know `innerText`, you need to use `textContent`, or a fix like:

```
rule_string = rule_string.innerText || rule_string.textContent;
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpDHL/1/).

---

As a side note: Looks like your app is based on global variables. Please don't use this kind of programming technique. It'll do the job, as long as there's not much of code, but when your apps are getting larger, you'll lose control over a ton of global variables.

For starters, you can read [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) at MDN, especially chapters 4, 8 and 9.

Comment: @CertDoctor If you can use the answer, you could also accept it by ticking the checkmark on the top-left corner of the answer.